# Printing a URL if it has a certain keyword

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have function which extracts the urls from espn. the urls looks like this http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/13224/scorecard/426406/scotland-vs-england-only-odi-england-in-scotland-odi-match-2010, http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/13240/scorecard/426384/ireland-vs-australia-only-odi-australia-tour-of-england-and-ireland-2010

I have created a list of countries and I wanted to print a message if the url contains country from the list else pass to extracting next url

```
all_countries=['England','India','West Indies']

#one_day will have all the links
for day in one_day:
        d=day.split('-')
        if d in all_countries:
            print(day)
        else:
            next
```

It doesnt work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: add your country list

Comment: Remove `else: next`.

Comment: Note that `d` contains a list. But you are comparing it against strings, so `if d in all_countries` will always fail.

Comment: I am afraid `d` is not what you think. Take a look at that.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for some tips on debugging your code. In particular, you should add `print(d)` to see its value.

Comment: `d=day.split('-')` will yield a list such as `['scotland', 'vs', 'england', 'only']`.  That list, as a whole, is certainly not present in `all_countries`.

Comment: Note that `else: next` doesn't do what you think it does and you can remove it entirely.

Comment: I have added the country list. To confirm, if the list doesnt have the country name it should move to other function. so we dont have to use else:next here?

Comment: Your logic to parse the URL needs to be more sophisticated. First of all, you can ignore everything before the last `/`. Secondly, you need to find just the country names in the rest of the string.

Comment: Thank you all for your support and help. I got it working:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `.split()` returns a list. You would have to iterate the items of your list. Essentially what you are asking the computer is if

```
["http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/13224/scorecard/426406/scotland", "vs", "england", "only", "odi", "england", "in", "scotland", "odi", "match", "2010"]
```

Is in some list that looks like this (I assume):

```
["england", "scotland", "ireland", ...]
```

I suggest you use a few print statements. A simple `print(d)` would show this behaviour. You would have to iterate over `d`:

```
for word in d:
    if word in all_countries:
        print(word)
        break # otherwise multiple words will trigger your logic multiple times
```

Comment: I think if we specify `.split()` `["http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/13224/scorecard/426406/scotland", "vs", "england", "only", "odi", "england", "in", "scotland", "odi", "match", "2010"]` is produced and the last word of the first index is ignored in this case which is unfortunately a country name. It would be better if we can use regex and specify the separators in split as per the requirement.  For example: `import re` `d=re.split("[^a-zA-Z]", day)`

Comment: @KiranMayeeMaddi hmmm, yeah good point. Although OP could `.split("/")` if they really wanted to process the parts of the URL at the beginning! Thanks for pointing that out though

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward way to do it (assuming `one_day` is a list of urls, and `all_countries` is a list of country names):

```py
# (some example values for urls and country names) 
one_day = ['http://www.espncricinfo.com/...-vs-australia-only-odi-au...', 
           'http://www.espncricinfo.com/...scotland-vs-england-only-...'] 
all_countries = ['India', 'Ireland', 'Australia'] 

for day in one_day:
  for country in all_countries:
    if country.lower() in day:
      print(f'found a match for {country}: `{day}`')
      # or just: print(day)
```

This works because `in` checks for substring, e.g.:

```py
'Australia'.lower() in '...-vs-australia-only-odi-au...'
## True
```

That's what you're checking at each iteration of the inner loop in the condition `country.lower() in day`.

p.s. you could also split on `'-'` as in the original post, in case you are worried about cases like e.g. `'USA'` matching a url containing `'-musac...'` or something like that. To do that, you could say something like this:

```py
for day in one_day:
  day_split = day.split('-')
  for elem in day_split:
    if elem in [c.lower() for c in all_countries]:
      print(f'found a match: `{day}`')
```

Answer (score 1):

or with regex is more flex ;):

```
import re

urls = ["http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/13224/scorecard/426406/scotland-vs-england-only-odi-england-in-scotland-odi-match-2010",
        "http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/13240/scorecard/426384/ireland-vs-australia-only-odi-australia-tour-of-england-and-ireland-2010",
        "http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/13240/scorecard/426384/titi-2010"
       ]

countries = ['England',
             'India',
             'West Indies']

for url in urls:
    if bool(re.match('(?i).*?(' + '|'.join(countries).replace(' ', '\W') + ').*?', url)):
        print(url)
```

results:

```
http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/13224/scorecard/426406/scotland-vs-england-only-odi-england-in-scotland-odi-match-2010
http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/13240/scorecard/426384/ireland-vs-australia-only-odi-australia-tour-of-england-and-ireland-2010
```

Comment: I dislike regex. As the saying goes, "There once was a programmer that had a problem. He decided he would solve it with regex. He now had two problems" XD

Comment: I have three issues because I'm chemist ^^. But Regex is very cool when you would like to code something which matches some stuffs with flexibility :)

Comment: This seems interesting. Do you have any links that I can refer to understand this method and learn about it?

Answer (score 0):

In your case

```
all_countries=['England','India','West Indies']
    for day in one_day:
            d=day.split('-')
            if d in all_countries:
                print(day)
            else:
                next
```

you are doing `d = day.split('-')`
d is also a list so you need to iterate the d and then check value in country
one more point is that you all_countries caontain Captlize country name so you need to convert them to lower case before checking if condition

here is code snippet that might help

```
all_countries=['England','India','West Indies']

for day in one_day:
    d=day.split('-')
    for val in d:
        if val.lower() in [x.lower() for x in all_countries ]:
            print(day)
        else:
            next
```